# Working with Spring JPA and eclipseLink, UUID as Id is binded in query as object reference

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, uuid

Im trying to use Spring and JPA. I have a table in Oracle of which few of the fields are RAW(16 BYTE) type. My entity looks like following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testTable")
public class TestTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Type(type = "uuid-binary")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "TABLE_ID")
    @Type(type = "uuid-binary")
    private UUID tableId;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;
```

My repository class looks like the following:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestTable, UUID> {

    TestTable getTestTableByTableId(@Param("table_id") UUId table_id);
}
```

The column i'm trying to mark as `@Param` is not primary key. I have enabled JPA Repositories on configuration file with @EnableJpaRepositories as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { TestRepository.class })
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {

        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.getDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.test.entity");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.vendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    //datasource properties here

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean()
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(this.entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
```

when i autowire the repository in my controller and invoke the method defined in the repository, JPA creates SQL in the background and tried to bind the parameter, but it is binding an object reference instead of UUID as follows:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-08-10 09:17:22.306--ServerSession(1292029763)--Connection(678757862)--SELECT ID, TABLE_ID, STATUS FROM TESTTABLE WHERE (TABLE_ID= ?)
    bind => [[B@2f6964a4]
```

My question is why is it binding it as an object? and how would I resolve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, try to change type from uuid-binary to uuid-char.

Comment: @duardito changed the type as you mentioned, still trying to bind as an object reference.

Comment: so, maybe you should use varchar type. you will store uuid as string. I used it before and stores in DB as varchar.

Comment: @duardito thats the problem, I have this field in DB as RAW(16 BYTE) type and this configuration works fine with `HibernateJpaVendorAdaptor`, just cant get it to work with `EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdaptor`